# iOS 14 read contacts using ionic

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, ionic-framework, mobile

I have been working with an ionic app that need to read phone's contacts. Before iOS upgrade to version 14, everything was working ok, but now every time I want to read the contacts, the app crashes and get this error message: `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController does not support subclassing in iOS 7.0 and later. In the future, a nil instance will be returned.`

I have declared the `NSContactsUsageDescription` in the info.plist file.

Here's my code for contact reading in ionic

```
searchContact() {
  this.contactService.pickSingleContact().then((response: Contact) => {
    console.log(response);
    this.name = response.name.givenName + " " + response.name.familyName;
    this.phone = response.phoneNumbers[0].value.toString();
  });
  this.inputDisabled = true;
}

pickSingleContact() {
  return this.contacts.pickContact();
}
```

I hope you can help me

Comment: Have you found out the solution here with Ionic 3?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ContactsUI` instead of `AddressBookUI`

For ex; you can't use [cordova-plugin-contacts](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-contacts). Instead, you can use [cordova-plugin-contacts-x](https://github.com/EinfachHans/cordova-plugin-contacts-x) if you only need reading contacts feature.